# Is the wait(timeout) unreliable ?

Tags: java, multithreading

after the timeout, the thread will also need to compete for the own of the monitor or the lock.

then, at the worst case, this could be a long time, and much longer then the timeout

is it?

Comment: Uhm, relevant code please?

Comment: In the _worst_ case, the lock is deadlocked, and the wait() call will _never_ return :-)

Comment: yes! james, wish you NERVER deadlock :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You have no guarantee when the thread will next execute. Just that it will happen sometime after the sleep time

Things like the `ScheduledExecutorService` mitigate this with `scheduleAtFixedRate` but they still cannot guarantee that it will run exactly at that time.

To avoid this you need a Real Time Operating System.

However in practice most computers are fast enough that this just isn't an issue unless you are doing something that is incredibly time-critical. The thread will execute within miliseconds of your desired time most of the time.

Comment: It also breaks under heavy load, which is a real threat.